# what is the correct name for "rich" views?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, oracle, view

I was reading about this the other day that with a good DB you can create a view of data, that is automatically updated and cached

say you have:

- time user was online
- this is measured with 2 datetimes, start and end date
- many entries
- what is the total time?

this would be an example of a "rich" view

a view that selects all entries, and adds up the dates, and provides them in a view

when a value is updated, automatically the view is updated

now I don't know the word for it.

**What is the proper term for it?**

I know mysql does not support it (at least that is what I think)

Comment: "I was reading about this the other day" where were you reading about this? AFAIK you're just creating that term out of thin air which makes it too localized. Cite the source and give us a direct quote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Materialized view.

[Overview of Materialized Views](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/cncpt/partitions-views-and-other-schema-objects.html#GUID-2822B62B-CAF3-4DCE-B4D6-5E677FB8A829)

[Materialized Views](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rules-materializedviews.html)

Comment: I guess there is no type of mysql that supports that, right?

Comment: this is almost a "link only" answer that is unwanted on dba.stackexchange

Answer (score 1):

A view is nothing but a stored query. There is nothing to "update" about it.  Since it is nothing but a query, whenever you select from the view, you inherently get the latest data from the  underlying tables.  A view does not take any space (other than an entry in the data dictionary) because it is just a query.  It doesn't store any data of its own.

Perhaps you mean a "materialized view", but your actual description is rather unclear.  In Oracle a materialized view is an actual table, along with rules on how and how often to refresh it with data from other tables.

[Concepts](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/schemaob.htm#CNCPT88875)

[SQL Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_6002.htm#SQLRF01302)